# Possible to get stomach discomfort because of meditation?

Tags: personal-practice

I have been starting meditation more recently for about twenty minutes at a time. I am able to slightly focus on the breath and have noticed I focus better when the breathes are long. I have also noticed after these sessions I may have air in my stomach possibly that leads to gas buildup and stomach discomfort. Is this something others have had before? If so how can I prevent this?

Comment: I guess you may be swallowing saliva and with it some air - without noticing it?

Comment: I have read that walking meditation aids in digestion, while sitting meditation actually inhibits it. So it follows that walking before sitting, especially if you have eaten prior, may help with queasiness you're experiencing.

Comment: Still face the same conditions may sine of mental reaction for the meditation.

Comment: @Ian that's very interesting! Do you have any references about that so I can learn more?

Comment: @AndreiVolkov it is possible I do swallow saliva and air to eliminate it from my mouth. How should one remove that from mouth so it doesn't become object of distraction during meditation?

Comment: @Shrawaka I'm not sure that I understand. Could you clarify?

Comment: @user3547 try raising your tongue and keep it touching the roof - to have saliva flow back in your throat. Also, like Ahmed said below - relax, don't try too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible Causes:

- You are eating too much and too soon to doing sitting meditation. **While meditating or doing any relaxing activity, your digestive system functions much better** thus producing more gas along with other things. Solutions: eat less and have at least an hour or two gap for meditation or try a different posture like standing/non-lotus.
- You are stresing out (more than normal) while you are trying to relax (meditate) thus causing intenstinal ineffectiveness. Let go of those thinkings and be present and pleasant.
- You are already quite gassy. Have some probiotics in the form of yogurt, kombucha, or fermented food.

Comment: All three suggestions are very good ideas. Do you know if it is ok to drink water 15 minutes before meditation? Or is that also not recommended?

Comment: Water is fine.. as much as you like. Too much can cause sitting discomfort.

Answer (score 1):

Same experience of air in stomach some 20 years ago.

Just carried on meditation. It will go away.

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to slightly focus on the breath and have noticed I focus better when the breathes are long.

You have to be able to concentrate when breaths are short also. Look at this as a training for a major competitions. When you take up the sport the exercises are light as easy as you go on it becomes intense.

If you are to see the mind-matter process at the level of subatomic particles you have to be able to be sensitive to the subtlest of breaths and also in places which a the least sensitive to for a beginner like the centre of the upper lip though this becomes very sensitive beyond a certain point. You need not start with this but this is where your focus should be after some pratice.

> I have also noticed after these sessions I may have air in my stomach possibly that leads to gas buildup and stomach discomfort. Is this something others have had before? If so how can I prevent this?

Maybe you are swallowing air. This could be the case. Or generally you have become sensitive to your digesting process which you didn't notice before. Heavy meals can do this perhaps. Try lighter meals. Sometimes based on olf Karma practitioners get certain recurring issues for a period. See if this is the case after a few months.

If you have a teacher discuss this with him / her. If not perhaps you can try visiting one or andd organised course where you have a chance to discuss these issues with a teacher. Some easily accessible courses are: https://www.dhamma.org/en/index, http://www.internationalmeditationcentre.org/global/index.html, or alternatively search World Buddhist Directory - http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same problem. I wasn't eating before meditation and it continued to be a problem to the next day. So I think above advice on eating does not apply. I am sorry but haven't found a solution neither. Maybe walking meditation could be a good alternativ.
Best,
Jasmin